# Dynamically reset the values using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a section where i paginate.

The pagination works fine but is it possible to dynamically reset the pagination based on the number receive from `inputtext` using `jquery`.

For Eg:

In My pagination it displays `1 2 3`.

Now i got a number `100`.

So the pagination section should reset to `100` where `100` being the **active element** and the numbers being `100 101 102`.

Now if 101 is the last page.
Then it should be highlighting on 100 number and 101 last.

Again i enter 50
So the pagination section should reset to 50 51 52 where 50 being highlighted.

When i tried it disrupts the flow very badly. Below is what i been working upon.

Firstly how would pagination detect that number has been entered in textbox(the alert that i have written in javascript).

Any advice much appreciated.

```js
$('ul.pagination').on('click', 'a', function() { // listen for click on pagination link

var a=+50;
alert("number received"+a);
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
  
    var active_elm = $('ul.pagination a.active');
  
    if(this.id == 'next'){
      var _next = active_elm.parent().next().children('a');
      if($(_next).attr('id') == 'next') {
        
        // appending next button if reach end
        var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())+1;
        active_elm.removeClass('active');
        $('.three_links').first().remove();
     $('.three_links').last().after('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
        return; 
      }
      _next.addClass('active');   
      
      
      
      
    }
    else if(this.id == 'prev') {
      var _prev = active_elm.parent().prev().children('a');
      if($(_prev).attr('id') == 'prev'){
       var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())-1;
        if(num > 0){
          active_elm.removeClass('active');
         $('.three_links').last().remove();
      $('.three_links').first().before('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
        }
        return;
      }
      _prev.addClass('active');   
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    active_elm.removeClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

div.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#" id="prev">«</a></li>
    <li class="three_links"><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="three_links"><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="three_links"><a id="test3" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to always highlight a number in the center of the paginator?

Comment: @madalinivascu :
 
not in the centre it should be leftmost. Like when there is 1 2 3 and 1 is being highlighted. and i get number 50 then 50 should be highlighted and in pagination it should be 50 leftmost then 51 then 52.

Comment: You want to replace 1,2,3 with 100,101,102 or you have all these page and want to navigate to 100th page if someone enter 100 ? Sorry but not understanding your requirement. Please make it clear to me if possible.

Comment: @ManojLodhi In my navigation section i only want when it gets 100. The pagination section should display 100 101 102 and highlight on 100. Navigation i will handle. I just want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, May be it helps you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#paging" ).keyup(function() {
   var val = this.value;
   if(!val || val < 1){return;}
   $( ".pagination li a" ).removeClass( "active" );
   $( ".pagination li" ).each(function(index, event) {
    if(index != 0 && index != 4){
    if(index == 1){
     $( this ).children('a').addClass( "active" );
    }
    $( this ).children('a').text(val);
    val++;
   }
  });
 });
});
```

In HTML, I have added a input box

```
 <input type='number' id='paging'></input>
 <div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
   <li><a href="#" id="prev">«</a></li>
   <li class="three_links"><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
   <li class="three_links"><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
   <li class="three_links"><a id="test3" href="#">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

It will take value from input on keyup, You can change this keyup event according to your need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used a very basic and simple solution for this. I created a function onclick of textbox where page number is entered and i did something below in the function:

```
function test()
{
   var num = 27 //Assuming 27 is the number
   $('#test1').html(27);
   $('#test2').html(28);//Add 1
   $('#test3').html(29); // Add 2
}
```